# ksoap2 Parameter not getting paased to the wsdl created by jax-ws

Tags: android, jax-ws, android-ksoap2

Please tell me what i am doiong wrong as my wsdl is getting called but the parameters are not getting passed .
ksoap2 Parameter not getting passed created in android to the wsdl created by jax-ws.the parameter shows the null value on the sever.

```
                SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

                PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
                unameProp.name="arg0";
                unameProp.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                unameProp.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
               request.addProperty(unameProp,"argo");//Pass properties to the variable

                PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
                passwordProp.name="arg1";
                passwordProp.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                passwordProp.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);

               request.addProperty(passwordProp,"arg1");
                System.out.println("pppppppppppppppppp2222");

                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;

                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

             HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
             //   AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
            //SoapPrimitive resultsrequestSOAP=null;
    //         androidHttpTransport.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
                System.out.println("oblje");
             //   SoapObject soapResponse = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();//throws the soap fault exception at this line
    //            Log.i("myApp", soapResponse.toString());

                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); 
                //resultsrequestSOAP=(SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                System.out.println("call success");
                   SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
                 System.out.println(response.toString()+"oooo");
            }
            catch (Exception ex2){`enter code here`
                System.out.println("EXCEPTION: " + ex2.getMessage());

            }
```

My web service code is

```
@WebMethod(operationName="authenticaton", action="urn:authenticaton")
public String authenticaton(@WebParam(name="uid")String arg0, @WebParam(name="passwd")String arg1){
    System.out.println(arg0+"abcfgdffguh");
//  TestModel testmodel=new TestModel();
//  System.out.println("Success");
//  return testmodel.authentication(str1, str2);
    System.out.println("tgfgfgfgh");
    return "success";
}

<definitions name="TestSessionService" targetNamespace="http://session/">
−
    <types>
−
    <xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://session/" schemaLocation="TestSessionService_schema1.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
−
    <message name="authenticaton">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:authenticaton">
    </part>
</message>
−
    <message name="authenticatonResponse">
<part name="parameters" element="tns:authenticatonResponse">
    </part>
</message>
−
    <portType name="TestSession">
−
    <operation name="authenticaton">
<input message="tns:authenticaton">
    </input>
<output message="tns:authenticatonResponse">
    </output>
</operation>
</portType>
−
    <binding name="TestSessionPortBinding" type="tns:TestSession">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
−
    <operation name="authenticaton">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:authenticaton"/>
−
    <input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</input>
−
    <output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
−
    <service name="TestSessionService">
−
    <port name="TestSessionPort" binding="tns:TestSessionPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://172.16.1.23:9080/TestWebEjb_HTTPRouter/TestSessionService"/>
</port>
</service>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not setting your property value in request,
I am guessing arg0 and arg1 are your input parameter name, you can set it's value like below,

```
             PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
             unameProp.name="arg0";
             unameProp.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
             unameProp.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
             unameProp.setValue("value of arg0 i.e. username") /*add your value here*/
             request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable, this will set your value in arg0.

            PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
            passwordProp.name="arg1";
            passwordProp.type=PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
            passwordProp.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
            passwordProp.setValue("value of arg1 i.e. password") /*add your value here*/
           request.addProperty(passwordProp);
```

I think above tweaks will fix your problem.

**Edited:**

```
my web service code is like this 
    @WebMethod(operationName="authenticaton", action="urn:authenticaton") public String authenticaton(@WebParam(name="uid")String arg0, @WebParam(name="passwd")String arg1){}
```

---

```
(@WebParam(name="uid")
@WebParam(name="passwd")
```

here you are setting input parameter arg0 name as"uid". Similarly for password your input parameter name is "passwd" not arg1.

Make changes in your code as follows,

```
unameProp.name="uid";
passwordProp.name="passwd";
```

Comment: I have also tried this but this is also not able to pass any parameters to my wsdl

Comment: Are you passing those parameters value directly or you are using any variable in your code to insert username and password?can you paste the code part where you are extracting argo and arg1 in your code.can you show me your wsdl input message, i mean what's format your webservice expecting?

Comment: my web service code is like this @WebMethod(operationName="authenticaton", action="urn:authenticaton")
public String authenticaton(@WebParam(name="uid")String arg0, @WebParam(name="passwd")String arg1){
 System.out.println(arg0+"abcfgdffguh");
// TestModel testmodel=new TestModel();
// System.out.println("Success");
// return testmodel.authentication(str1, str2);
 System.out.println("tgfgfgfgh");
 return "success";
}